# some commands of external css file are not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website for which i have created an external css file , problem is some of the commands from the external css file are not working while using the same commands as an internal css it's working perfectly. what could be the possible error?
Here is the code for working internal css:

```
<style>
 .top img{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
 }
</style>
```

and this one is from the external css file which is not working.

```
.top img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

P.S. i'm working in HTML 5 and using bootstrap as well!

Comment: It is not clear what is not working, nor why it wouldn’t be with the code you have shown. Please provide a proper [mre] that illustrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the sequence of importing the external file. CSS works based on the top-down approach. or alternatively, you can try with the following

```
.top img{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out that there isn't any error in the code. Actually any update done in the external css file wasn't working becuase it wasn't imported properly and using

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?<?=filemtime("css/style.css")?>">
```

instead of

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

solved the issue.